# jump search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

i am doing jump search algorithm but it show me    that element is not in array while it is
here is code

```
import java.math.*; 

public class  jamp  {

    public  static int min(int a,int b) {
        return a<b?a:b;
    }

    public  static void main(String[]args) {
        int  a[]=new int[]{3,7,9,12,14,15,16,17,18};
        int l=14;
        System.out.println(jumpsearch(a,a.length,l));
    }

    public static int jumpsearch(int a[],int n, int  l ) {
        int t=0;
        int b=(int)Math.sqrt(n);
        while (a[min(b,n)-1]<t){
            t=b;
            b=b+(int)Math.sqrt(n);
            if ( t>=n)  return  -1  ;
        }
        while (a[t]<l){
            t=t+1;
            if ( t==min(b,n))    
                return   -1  ;
            if ( a[t]==l)  {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: A friendly piece of advice: stop giving your variables one letter names, it makes the code you produce very hard to penetrate even if there's not much of it. Getting into the habit of properly naming your variables will ensure that any future code-buddies will be happy campers.

Comment: Use a debugger, which you can find in the most well-known Java IDEs such as Eclipse or NetBeans to step through the code line by line, and follow what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
while (a[min(b,n)-1]<t){
```

to

```
while (a[min(b,n)-1]<l){ // t should be l
```

According to this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_search) that value should be the search key. When I run the program with this change I get 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample Example for Jump Search(Alternative Approach):- 
Hope this helps

```
public class JumpSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr= {0,1,2,3,4,5,5,9,12,14,15,15};
        System.out.println("Element found at: "+search(arr,15));
    }
    public static int  search (int[] arr,int key){
        int length= arr.length;
        int start=0;
        int jump=(int) Math.sqrt(length);
        for(int i=0;i<length;i+=jump){
            if(arr[i]==key){
                return i;
            }
            else if(arr[i]>key){
                start=arr[i-jump];
                break;
            }else{
                start=i+1;
            }
        }
        for(int i=start;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==key){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function jumpSearch($arr,$length,$searched_value){
$step=sqrt($length);
for($i=0;$arr[$i]<=$searched_value;$i=$i+$step){
    if($arr[$i]==$searched_value){
        return $i;
    }else{
        $last_up=$i;
    }
}
$s=$last_up+1;
$l=$s+$step;
for($i=0;$i<=$l;$i++){
    if($arr[$i]==$searched_value){
        return $i;
    }
}    
}

$arr=array(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610);
$length=count($arr);
$searched_value=34;
$result=jumpSearch($arr,$length,$searched_value);
if($result==-1){
}else{
    echo "Search Found at ".$result;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer an implicit (if that) question about code in and tagged Java?