# Search Algorithm error regarding first index value

Tags: java

Hi I am taking a look at this post in the link below regarding this search algorithm and when I tried to run it, everything works correctly by printing out the index value of the number(l) you are searching for but if the number(l) you are searching for is the first element in the array then it just prints -1 instead of 0.What correction needs to be made in this program? Lets say int l = 3, then it should print 0.

The code below is from this post 
    [jump search algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882362/jump-search-algorithm?newreg=1f1595368f3b4feda8ea9f04a9319970) with the correction as stated by Alex Winston.

I followed along exactly what this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_search posted regarding this algorithm's implementation

```
import java.math.*; 

public class  jamp  {

public  static int min(int a,int b) {
    return a<b?a:b;
}

public  static void main(String[]args) {
    int  a[]=new int[]{3,7,9,12,14,15,16,17,18};
    int l=14;                                            //lets say int l = 3;
    System.out.println(jumpsearch(a,a.length,l));
}

public static int jumpsearch(int a[],int n, int  l ) {
    int t=0;
    int b=(int)Math.sqrt(n);
    while (a[min(b,n)-1]<l){
        t=b;
        b=b+(int)Math.sqrt(n);
        if ( t>=n)  return  -1  ;
    }
    while (a[t]<l){
        t=t+1;
        if ( t==min(b,n))    
            return   -1  ;
        if ( a[t]==l)  {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return -1;            // if this is 0, then it works but if you search for a element that is not in the array then it still prints 0 which is incorrect
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is lying in this section:

```
  while (a[t]<l){
        t=t+1;
        if ( t==min(b,n))    
            return   -1  ;
        if ( a[t]==l)  {
            return t;
        }
 }
```

For `l = 3`, so after the first loop, `t = 0` and `a[t] == l`, so the condition of the while loop `a[t] < l` is false, so your program directly return -1 without entering the loop.

You can add a condition check before entering this loop:

```
if(a[t] == l)
   return t;
while(a[t] < l){
  //the rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: Ah I should have seen such a simple fix, Thanks boss!